# Android app does not ask for notifications permission

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native Expo android app, and I choose to ask for permissions when the user and socket (from websocket world) are set. In dev it works, but when I upload to app store (as the internal testing), it does not ask for permissions.

```
 "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": ["NOTIFICATIONS", "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"],
      "package": "com.xxx.xxxx",
      "versionCode": 4
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => {
    return {
      shouldShowAlert: true,
      shouldPlaySound: false,
      shouldSetBadge: false,
    }
  },
});

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(async token => {
        setPushToken(token)
        console.log(token)
      });

      notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
        setNotification(notification);
      });

      responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });

      return () => {
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current);
        Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current);
      };
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
      <someComponent />
  );
}

async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token;
  if (Constants.isDevice) {
    console.log("isDevice");
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    console.log(finalStatus)
    try {
      token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }

  console.log(token)
  return token;
}
```

Some of the apps code has been cut out, because it was not relevant to this post.

Comment: is the notifications permission allowing automatically?

Comment: Have you uploaded the credentials (in case of iOS)? and FCM setup (in case of Android)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to post the server key found in your firebase project. Check out FCM setup for expo.